# Javascript Not outputting 0 on one of the variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with my code here.
I'm doing a small project for fun but there is a small issue that' I don't understand.

My project is a basic small calculation: 1 block = 9 Ingots. A user inputs the amount of ingots and gets the amount of blocks and ingots they will get. I have a function to check if the input is a number but that's not the issue here.

JavaScript:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // Get the input assign it to 'value'
  var value = document.getElementById('input').value;

  // Define variables and set them to 0
  var value_ingot = 0;
  var value_block = 0;

  // Add 1 to block if value is 9 or higher
  //   Remove 9 from value
  while (value > 8){
    value = value - 9;
    value_block ++;
  }
  value_ingot = value;
  value = value - value;

  // This makes it output: '0 Blocks' and ' Ingots' if the input is empty
  document.getElementById("blocks").innerHTML = value_block + " Blocks";
  document.getElementById("ingots").innerHTML = value_ingot + " Ingots";
}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<h4 id="blocks" class="c_top">0 Blocks</h4>
<h4 id="ingots" class="c_top">0 Ingots</h4>
<input onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" id="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="8"/>
```

Any idea of what might cause this, any way to fix it?

Thank you for reading :)
-Aleksander

Comment: what variable? your question seems weird

Comment: @cr0ss 'value_ingot' is outputting '' if the input is empty. I need it to stay '0' if the input is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the input value is empty and that won't automatically typify to a zero int as you need.

Try forcing it to zero when it's empty.

```
var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
if(!value) value = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying different ways for hours now.

Comment: Using `var value = +document.getElementById('input').value;` on it would be more natural and return 0 if the string is empty(notice the `+` sign that converts the string to a number) Try to paste this in your console: `+""`

Answer (score 0):

The value of value is "" (empty string) if you don't enter anything. You then assign "" to value_ingots which is what you are seeing in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The `0 Ingots` is displayed, and then replaced by the JS function `setInterval()`.

The interval doesn't seem pragmatic with your question, using `onclick=` or `onblu=` you will handle the input better.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more intuitive:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('input');

myInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
  var v = +myInput.value;
  document.getElementById("blocks").innerHTML = Math.floor(v/9) + " Blocks";
  document.getElementById("ingots").innerHTML = (v%9) + " Ingots";
});

function isNumber(e){
  return !isNaN(parseInt(String.fromCharCode(e.which), 10));
}
```

```html
<h4 id="blocks">0 Blocks</h4>
<h4 id="ingots">0 Ingots</h4>
<input id="input" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" type="text"/>
```